# Тень только по бокам

Tags: css

Как сделать, чтобы тень была только по бокам?

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px 0 rgba(146,146,146,1);
box-shadow:0 0 15px 0 rgba(146,146,146,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.boxShadow {
  box-shadow:
   0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3),
   -23px 0 20px -23px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8),
   23px 0 20px -23px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8),
   0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;
}
```

Comment: вот ваш вариант: http://ssmaker.ru/a6356c00.jpg
а нужно так: http://ssmaker.ru/8a4414fe.png

Comment: ну так внутреннею тень уберите, и дело в шляпе.
на вашем примере, кстати, тень по периметру, а не бокам.